# PHP at WordPress site cannot create cookie only on Login page

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, centos

I've experience issue with wordpress on centos 7 with httpd, I can't login and it say cookie block. I've try on some device the result is also same.

I've try a lot of recommendation in and not working,

for example

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', false);
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

this one isn't working.

Or set cookie to my domain also not working.

I also try to create a file using tutorial from https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_network_setcookie.asp and also not working. I'm not sure this is server side problem or wordpress. the funny thing is the cookies are created if visiting the homepage, so the problem is only on login page

So anyone have ever experience same issue with mine? or any solution for my problem?

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: @FluffyKitten I didn't get any script error, just say "Error: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress." and it's  already enable

Comment: That sounds more like a browser issue. Cookies for that specific page might have been blocked accidentally. Have you tried in a different browser?

Comment: @FluffyKitten I've try on some device and still not working

Answer (score 0):

I change the server to NGINX and it's work normal, but this is not solution that I want since I want my server running on Apache

Answer (score -1):

try to add this code on *wp-config.php*:

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN’, false);
```

Comment: The OP has already said in their question that they tried that.